# Getting back to game page from xaml page problem. (Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: xna, monogame, windows-phone-8

I have implemented a xaml page where user can submit his score. I have managed to get the user to the xaml page, after 2 hours of struggling but I do not know how can I navigate the user back to the game page, because I got nothing but black screen.

This is the code, I used to navigate to submit score xaml page:

```
var frame = new Frame();
frame.Navigate(typeof(SubmitScoreDialog));

Window.Current.Content = frame;
Window.Current.Activate();
```

I used the same code, to get the user back to game page, after he submited his score, but I get that black screen, nothing is drawn ... I do not know how can I get this working.
Here is the code from **SubmitScoreDialog.xaml.cs** to get the user back to game page.

```
var frame = new Frame();
frame.Navigate(typeof(GamePage));

Window.Current.Content = frame;
Window.Current.Activate();
```

If anyone can provide me the working code for this problem, I will be very thankful.

Comment: can't you just write the score to a file when the user cliks a "submit" button after the game ends ? why do you need to redirect the user to something else ?

Comment: Because I want to make a global leaderboard :P

Comment: so i write it in a database ? or write it somewhere programmatically, why does the user have to physically write it ?

Comment: Ok, and how can I write it programmatically, where? I forgot to mention but I am using App42 to store the scores, this I think is the best method to do it. Even though I don't use xaml page to submit I will need a xaml page to display the leaderboard..

Comment: i don't know what xaml is. why don't you simply have a .txt or .xml  in your dropbox/server, or a database in your server, and read/write that file (or database table) to display/save the game score in the screen ? `database would been ideal`, but a .txt/.xml on a remote server would have almost the same result (but much slower, less secure and more memory usage i suppose)

Comment: And how can i open a server for my app? Anyway ... Could you just please help me solve my initial problem, to get my game page working, I just want to try my method and if it doesn't work I will look for another alternatives. Thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunately i don't know how to solve your actual problem. However, how are you planning to have a global scoreboard for all the users, with no server being involved ? How is that possible exactly ? As for "how can i open a server" i assumed you already had one, because of the context of your question, which is having a global scoreboard

Comment: Yeah, actually I do not have problem saving and showing the scores (I am using app42 as I said), I just have problems navigating through pages, from game page to a custom xaml page and back.

Comment: Shiro "I don't know what XAML is" "I don't know how to solve your actual problem." these are indications that you absolutely should not be attempting to answer this question. You can't know anything about Windows Phone development and not know what XAML is.

Comment: Ok, I would really like that someone will solve my problem. Thanks.